# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Triggering a Search From outside of autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I would like to trigger some jQuery autocomplete events from outside of autocomplete but I don't know how to. i.e.

```
$("something").autocomplete({select:function(event,ui){do x},
                                search:function(event,ui){do y}});

$("something else").keypress(function(eventobject){*trigger autocomplete "select"*});
```

What code do I put in *trigger autocomplete "select"*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the "Search" method: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

```
$("something").autocomplete(/* options */);
$("somethingelse").click(function () {
    $("something").autocomplete('search', 'demo-value');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Doc, sometimes it right infront of your face in the docs and you just can't see it.

Comment: for me this doesn't trigger the select event :)

Comment: This is for triggering the search event. See documentation and 'select' for that.