# Execute jquery autocomplete on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a text field and a forum button (not submit). I would like the user to type in a location in the text field, then click the button. I want to the button to trigger an autocomplete event on the textfield which will call an ajax to return possible values.

I know how to do the actual mechanics of the autocomplete, but its the triggering via the button that I don't know how to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439736/jquery-ui-autocomplete-triggering-a-search-from-outside-of-autocomplete

Comment: I don't know how the `autocomplete` plugin works, i suggest you make your own, but the accepted answer for that question is what you need: `$("somethingelse").click(function () {// your code here.})`

Comment: just use `$(".buttonClass").click(function () {$("element").autocomplete('search');});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you probably want to use a library to achieve your result.

Ex : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

In your case, it would be something like that :

```
$('button').click(function() {
     $('input').autocomplete('enable');
});
```

as found on this page : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-enable

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants--*"I want to the button to trigger an autocomplete event on the textfield which will call an ajax to return possible values."* `enable` does not trigger a search for items.