# Jquery Autocomplte on load

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, onload

I have an question about the how to trigger autocomplete onload in jquery.

```
$("#inv_no").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: "gethint_set_inv_penjualan.php",  
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var ref_no = $("#ref_no");
        var po_no = $("#po_no");
        var inv_no = $("#inv_no");
        var ref_no_inv = $("#ref_no_inv");
        var datepicker2 = $("#datepicker2");
        var datepicker5 = $("#datepicker5");
        var datepicker4 = $("#datepicker4");
        var met_pemb = $("#met_pemb");
        var tenor = $("#tenor");
        var parties = $("#parties");
        var add1 = $("#add1");
        var add2= $("#add2");
        var add3= $("#add3");
        var phone= $("#phone");
        var fax= $("#fax");
        var email= $("#email");
        var npwp = $("#npwp");
        var rekening = $("#rekening");
        var bank = $("#bank");
        var atasnama= $("#atasnama");
        var cabang= $("#cabang");
        var ccy= $("#ccy");
        var vat_pcg = $("#vat_pcg");
        var Grand_Total = $("#Grand_Total");
        var vat = $("#vat");
        var diskon= $("#diskon");
        var out_amnt= $("#out_amnt");
        var paid_amnt= $("#paid_amnt");
        var aval_amnt_for_set= $("#aval_amnt_for_set");
        var settle_ref= $("#settle_ref");
        var settle_amnt= $("#settle_amnt");
        var select2= $("#select2");
        $(ref_no).val(ui.item.ref_no);
        $(po_no).val(ui.item.po_no);
        $(inv_no).val(ui.item.inv_no);
        $(ref_no_inv).val(ui.item.ref_no_inv);
        $(datepicker2).val(ui.item.datepicker2);
        $(datepicker5).val(ui.item.datepicker5);
        $(datepicker4).val(ui.item.datepicker4);
        $(met_pemb).val(ui.item.met_pemb);
        $(tenor).val(ui.item.tenor);
        $(parties).val(ui.item.parties_name);
        $(add1).val(ui.item.parties_add1);
        $(add2).val(ui.item.parties_add2);
        $(add3).val(ui.item.parties_add3);
        $(phone).val(ui.item.phone);
        $(fax).val(ui.item.fax);
        $(email).val(ui.item.email);
        $(npwp).val(ui.item.npwp);
        $(rekening).val(ui.item.rekening);
        $(bank).val(ui.item.parties_bank);
        $(atasnama).val(ui.item.atasnama);
        $(cabang).val(ui.item.cabang);
        $(ccy).val(ui.item.ccy);
        $(vat_pcg).val(ui.item.vat_pcg);
        $(Grand_Total).val(ui.item.Grand_Total);
        $(vat).val(ui.item.vat);
        $(diskon).val(ui.item.diskon);
        $(out_amnt).val(ui.item.out_amnt);    
        $(paid_amnt).val(ui.item.paid_amnt);
        $(avail_amnt_inv).val(ui.item.avail_amnt_inv);  
        $(settle_ref).val(ui.item.ref_no);  
        $(settle_amnt).val(ui.item.avail_amnt_inv); 
        $(select2).val(ui.item.sof); 
        
    }
});
```

I already put default value in field "inv_no", and the purpose is the screen will be filled with the default value. I already try some method but there is no progress in the html, when I open the screen.

Can someone help me with this case?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

From this post: [jQuery UI Autocomplete: Triggering a Search From outside of autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439736/jquery-ui-autocomplete-triggering-a-search-from-outside-of-autocomplete/4443680)

You can trigger it through the "Search" method: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

```
$("#inv_no").autocomplete(/* options */);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#inv_no").autocomplete('search', 'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE');
});
```

Comment: Hi John, thx for the answer.
After try the code. the other field is still empty.. the purpose is, because there is default value, the othe field will be filled automatically with that "default value"

Comment: what I mean is, the "inv_no" will be filled with the default value, and the other field will be process in "gethint_set_inv_penjualan.php" and the field in the html wii be fill aoutomatically..